# Allow ManyToMany Duplications on Symfony 5 (Doctrine)

Tags: php, database, postgresql, symfony, doctrine

I have a problem, it's for a school project and I need to allow duplications of the same relation between two entities on my app using Symfony 5 & Doctrine & postgresql .

I have a basicly a ManyToMany relation between Order and Products, I don't want to add fields for quantity, so I'm looking to count the number of occurences of the a same relation id_order & id_product on my order_product table, but I can't persist more than one same relation between order & product.

I searched and mainly saw people tryng to avoid duplications of the same relation, i'm looking for the exact contrary.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

When using relation with `Many` on at least one side of the relation, you get `Collection` on the opposite side. On the collection you can call `count()` method.

So if you need to calculate quantity of `Products` in your `Order`, your `Order` entity can look like this:

```php
/** @Entity */
class Order
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="orders")
     * @JoinTable(name="order_product")
     */
    private $products;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function countProducts(): int
    {
        return $this->products->count();
    }

    public function countProductsById(int $productId): int
    {
        return $this->products->filter(static function(Product $product) use ($productId) {
            return $product->getId() === $productId;
        })->count();
    }

    ...
}
```

PS: Also be aware that word `Order` is a reserved word in PostgreSQL. You need to either name your `Order` entity differently or escape the naming correctly.

Comment: Hello Holicz and thx for your answer, you answered the second part of my problem but first I need to allow duplications of the same relations. 

I edited the addProduct() on my order entity to allow the duplication of the same entity product in the order->products collection but on my database it doesn't persist it and don't allows duplications